# Every time I run an app I have to download new data

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, sqlite, core-data

I'm developing an iPhone app with latest SDK and XCode 4.5.2.

This question may be valid for any mobile platform.

I need to connect to a web service when app stars and download some information. This information could change on server: some registers could be deleted, updated or inserted.

I problem is that I don't know where to store that information. I think it's a bad idea to store it on device memory. I think it's better to store on a text file or a database. **What do you think?**

I have another question is: **How can I know if some data has been changed on server?** I think it's a bad idea to download the same data every time user stars app.

If I want to do this, connect to web service at star up, when splash screen is shown. **Where I have to put the code, on AppDelegate?**

Any suggestion are welcome.

Comment: Take a look on the web at a few subjects: RESTKit, Core Data, NSUserDefaults, push notifications, and Stanford U.'s introductory lectures to writing iOS apps.

Answer (score 3):

**Where I have to put the code, on AppDelegate?**

Having the code in AppDelegate is not a very good idea. Instead you can have a viewController as splash screen. Set this viewController as your rootViewController. Do your initial web service call here and once you are done with it move to the first screen of your application.

**How can I know if some data has been changed on server?**

You will have to communicate to the server your version of the data. So set a version number for the data at the server side and keep track of it while downloading data. So if you pass the version number to server when you call the web service, the server can decide if there is any new data available. This way you can avoid downloading data that you have already downloaded.

**where to store that information?**

It depends on the data size that you want to store. And its security.
I think using database like Sqlite3 is a good option.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And, what do you think about core data instead of Sqlite3? Sorry, I'm very new on Core data and Sqlite3 and i don't know if they are the same thing.

Comment: Core data is also a good option. But, if the size of data to be stored is more, Sqlite3 is a better option.

Comment: There will be three or four tables. One of them could have a lot of register ( > 1000). The other tables will have less than 100 registers (or rows). And also, there will be relations between them.

Comment: In this case both options are possibly good. I think you can go with core data. It might be faster than sqlite3 in this case.

Answer (score 1):

**Where I have to put the code, on AppDelegate?**

It depends on the behavior of your app as to where you decide to download the data. Typically if your app is supposed to display the latest data every time it goes to a new view then the data should be downloaded when that view is accessed. That way you will always be showing the latest available data to the user.

You would typically avoid putting too much into *application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:*, especially network connections as you dont know what kind of connection the user may have. If the connection takes an extended amount of time and *application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:* takes too long to return iOS will kill your application for taking too long to open which isn't good for the user experience at all.

**How can I know if some data has been changed on server?**

You will want to be passing either a last-modified timestamp or etag in the header of the response from the server. When you get the header response from the server you can than check against the previous last-modified data that you recieved or if the etag is different you know that the data has been changed. Doing it this way is a lot quicker than downloading all of the body to check a single parameter, if that parameter hasn't changed then you have just downloaded a bunch of data for nothing. I would discourage against versioning, versioning is more used for API changes rather than checking if data is out of date or not.

**Storage Location?**

It depends on the quantity of data you are going to be downloading, but I would advise using core data typically. The problem with storing data into a file and then saving that file is that every time you open the app you will have to break down that data into something useable before you can search through it etc. With core data you will have fully formed objects that you can search against using NSPredicate making everything a lot simpler to use in the long run.

If your just downloading a few settings then you could get away with something like a file or NSUserDefaults but if you are going to be displaying a list or collection of data to the user it's best to use core data.

Answer (score 0):

**How can I know if some data has been changed on server?**
Use a variable version in your application and server also. Send application variable version with API and compere both version before downloading the data.

**Where I have to put the code, on AppDelegate?**

either can use applicationDidBecomeActive or didFinishLaunchingWithOptions depend on your requirement
`- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`
**OR**
`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

**Where to store that information**
depending on the size of data and your requirement you can decide where to save the data

1. You can save data in **UserDefault**
2. You can save data as **File** in *NSTemporaryDirectory / NSDocumentDirectory / NSLibraryDirectory*. I think **NSDocumentDirectory** is fine for you.
3. You can save data in **sqlite** or **CoreData**